# Integer (number) to String

Tags: java

Here is my simple question

We can convert `integer, float, double` to String like `String s = "" + i;` so **why** do we need `String s = Integer.toString(i);` ? just requirements of OO programmig ?

Thanks

Comment: I think while you can do the following `"" + i`, it is not implied what the result is, e.g. in php this would return i as an integer. `Integer.toString(i)` is explicit and thus there is no confusion, which make it a better practice, even though programmers (including me) tend to use the other style.

Comment: It's also a convenience method for `Integer.toString(i, 10)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `"" + i` is a very bad practice. It converts to string by concatenating an empty string and an integer, which causes, internally, the creation of a `StringBuilder` instance, the appending of the empty string, the call to `Integer.toString()`, the appending of the conversion, and then the call to `StringBuilder.toString()`.

`Integer.toString()` does just what is needed : converting the integer to a string. It's thus much more efficient, and also much clearer and readable, because it tells what it does : converting an integer to a string.

Comment: +0: Usually simplicity and clarity is more important than performance. Writing relatively obscure code on the basis of performance, when its not needed is bad practice.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: because you think `"" + i` is clearer than `Integer.toString(i)`? I think it's the opposite. The second one tells exactly what it does : a conversion. Integer.toString is far from being obscure.

Comment: I suggest you should do what you consider to be clearer. For me its `"" + i`

Comment: @Carlos, Good point. I tend to think of `""+` as a unary operator which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`String s = "" + i;` is just a shortcut. The compiler translates this to something like `String s = "" + Integer.toString(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

"integer" is a basic type, and the compiler can implicitly convert it.

"Integer" is an object type, and has its own method to provide the conversion.

Comment: sounds good but still I don't see any difference while Integer is null

Answer (score 0):

In this site it makes a comparation of the 2 methods:
http://en.literateprograms.org/Convert_Integer_to_String_(Java)

I don't have time to probe but it is the same if you only do this?:
    String text = i;
I think only works with concatenation, but not in an assignment purely.
    String s = "" + i;
is not so good looking...

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
"" + i
```

is turned into

```
new StringBuilder().append(i).toString();
```

This creates three objects whereas

```
Integer.toString(i)
```

creates only 2.  This makes the later more efficient and can save you about 0.1 microsecond per call.

However, simplicity of code is usually more important than performance and the time it takes you to write/check/maintain a longer sequence of code is usually worth more than the few cycles you might save.

e.g. say `i` becomes a long type.  In the first case, you would not need to change the code, it would still be.

```
""+i
```

however the second example would need to be changed, everywhere it is used, to

```
Long.toString(i);
```

A minor change, but one which is likely to have been completely unnecessary.